# Functions decorator safety in python

Tags: python, decorator

How this code works? It is from chapter 8 in "Data Science by Scratch" from the gradient. Why do I need to wrap a function inside another fucntion? Is there a more readable way to achieve this execption handling? Here's the explanation for it.

> It is possible that certain step sizes will result in invalid inputs for our function. So we’ll need to create a “safe apply” function that returns infinity (which should never be the minimum of anything) for invalid inputs:

```
def safe(f):
    """return a new function that's the same as f,
    except that it outputs infinity whenever f produces an error"""
    def safe_f(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
             return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
             return float('inf')
    return safe_f
```

Comment: Please be more clear which part of the code is not clear to you. Is it the return of an infinite value? Is the the `try` and `except`? Is is the arguments to `f()`? Is it why this function works in your larger code?

Comment: I have a grasp on try and except and unpacking arguments. I understand the purpose behind the function just not the implementation. I guess an example function call would help my understand what's going on but there isn't one in the book.

Comment: You've got 2 great usage examples in the answers below, but keep in mind that the `safe` decorator is not always what you want to do, sometimes exceptions are more informative that an `inf` value

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was very helpful seeing actual function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say we have a trivial function like this:

```
def myfunc(n):
    return 42/n
```

and we do this:

```
print(myfunc(0))
```

We get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gash.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(myfunc(0))
  File "gash.py", line 12, in myfunc
    return 42/n
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Now we do this:

```
myfunc = safe(myfunc)
print(myfunc(0))
```

We get this:

```
inf
```

The second time we call `safe()` which returns a new function with the embedded exception handling.  We replace what the *name* "myfunc" refers to, now it refers to the returned function.  The original `myfunc` is not lost, it is called `f` inside the new one.

A `@safe` decorator is essentially doing the same thing as `myfunc = safe(myfunc)`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the function call:

Lets say I define an average function like this:

```
def naive_average(lst):
    return float(sum(lst))/len(lst)
```

What would happen if `lst` is empty ? or if it contains something that isn't numeric ?
**BOOM, exception !**

With the decorator you mentioned, the function would look like this

```
@safe
def naive_average(lst):
    return float(sum(lst))/len(lst)
```

and now, calling it on an empty `lst` would return `float('inf')` instead of an exception